# Is there a way to check session ID and signature sent by client without function call?

Tags: php, authentication, soap, nusoap

I am working on SOAP server. I wanted to know is there any way we can check client's session id and signature without creating any function. If there will be no such function how client will send those value? And if authentication fails no function call should be accepted.